# Implementing event synchronization primitives in JavaScript/TypeScript using async/await/Promises

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, async-await

I have a long, complicated asynchronous process in TypeScript/JavaScript spread across many libraries and functions that, when it is finally finished receiving and processing all of its data, calls a function `processComplete()` to signal that it's finished:

```
processComplete(); // Let the program know we're done processing
```

Right now, that function looks something like this:

```
let complete = false;

function processComplete() {
   complete = true;
}
```

In order to determine whether the process is complete, other code either uses timeouts or `process.nextTick` and checks the `complete` variable over and over again in loops. This is complicated and inefficient.

I'd instead like to let various `async` functions simply use `await` to wait and be awoken when the process is complete:

```
// This code will appear in many different places
await /* something regarding completion */;
console.log("We're done!");
```

If I were programming in Windows in C, I'd use an [event synchronization primitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_(synchronization_primitive)) and the code would look something like this:

```
Event complete;

void processComplete() {
   SetEvent(complete);
}

// Elsewhere, repeated in many different places
WaitForSingleObject(complete, INFINITE);
console.log("We're done!");
```

In JavaScript or TypeScript, rather than setting a boolean `complete` value to true, what exactly could `processComplete` do to make wake up any number of functions that are waiting using `await`? In other words, how can I implement an event synchronization primitive using `await` and `async` or `Promise`s?

Comment: That's exactly what a promise is.  Just resolve a promise & `await` it.

Comment: @SLaks I'm having trouble figuring out how to create the promise in advance so that things can await it, and then resolve it later when `processComplete` is called.

Comment: @JohnSpeeks it looks like you doing this in node. You can use events and have listeners subscribe to them.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code that triggers the process to start and the code that calls `processComplete`?

Comment: @Mark_M It's actually an Angular 5 application, running in Chrome. But I'd be fine pulling in some other dependencies if that event system exists as a generic library.

Comment: @Paulpro It's perhaps a few hundred lines of code overall, doing calls to multiple web services, subscribing to some [WAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Messaging_Protocol) messages, getting results and processing them and combining them, and then when everything is finally done and ready, it calls the function `processComplete()`. I'll work on editing the question to make this more clear.

Comment: @JohnSpeeks — oh, angular has a full-blown event system. Instead of passing around the `complete` variable, you would pass around the event emitter  or observable and subscribe to it as needed. https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Comment: Just replace the `complete = true;` with `resolve()` and wrap the whole thing into one huge Promise. Or take your time and refactor it all to be based on Promises.

Comment: @Mark_M That seems pretty close. I'd like to be able to use "await" rather than callback. The documentation you linked to mentions Rx.Observable, which perhaps could be worked into a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This pattern is quite close to your code:

```
const processComplete = args => new Promise(resolve => {
   // ...
   // In the middle of a callback for a async function, etc.: 
     resolve(); // instead of `complete = true;`
   // ...
}));

// elsewhere
await processComplete(args); 
console.log("We're done!");
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise.

Comment: This looks like it would just resolve the promise immediately without waiting for anything asynchronous to actually complete

Comment: I believe in OP's example, `processComplete` is really analogous to the `resolve` function. It is not the async task.

Comment: @KirillBulygin I'm not sure this is right. The existing code calls the `processComplete()` function when everything is done, but that function seems to no longer exist. At the time that happens, there will be perhaps 5 or 10 different functions waiting for the process to be complete.

Comment: @JohnSpeeks I see you've added "This code will appear in many different places" after I replied. I don't think that promises are right for you then. Try an event system as suggested in the comments.

Comment: @KirillBulygin I'd mentioned before that it would be appear in various places, in the text, but added that comment too to make it more clear. I still feel like this should be possible using `Promise` and `await` but I'm just not really sure how--there has to be some way to bridge the gap.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you mean by "other code" in this scenario. It sounds like you want to use some variation of the [delegation pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) or the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

A simple approach is to take advantage of the fact that JavaScript allows you to store an array of functions. Your `processComplete()` method could do something like this:

```
function processComplete(){
    arrayOfFunctions.forEach(fn => fn());
}
```

Elsewhere, in your other code, you could create functions for what needs to be done when the process is complete, and add those functions to the `arrayOfFunctions`.

If you don't want these different parts of code to be so closely connected, you could set up a completely separate part of your code that functions as a notification center. Then, you would have your other code tell the notification center that it wants to be notified when the process is complete, and your `processComplete()` method would simply tell the notification center that the process is complete.

Another approach is to [use promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

Answer (score 1):

> I have a long, complicated asynchronous process in TypeScript/JavaScript spread across many libraries and functions

Then make sure that every bit of the process that is asynchronous returns a promise for its partial result, so that you can chain onto them and compose them together or `await` them.

> When it is finally finished receiving and processing all of its data, calls a function `processComplete()` to signal that it's finished

It shouldn't. The function that starts the process should return a promise, and when the process is finished it should fulfill that promise.

If you don't want to properly promisify every bit of the whole process because it's too cumbersome, you can just do

```
function startProcess(…);
    … // do whatever you need to do
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        processComplete = resolve;
        // don't forget to reject when the process failed!
    });
}
```

> In JavaScript or TypeScript, rather than setting a boolean `complete` value to true, what exactly could `processComplete` do to make wake up any number of functions that are waiting using `await`?

If they are already `await`ing the result of the promise, there is nothing else that needs to be done. (The awaited promise internally has such a flag already). It's really just doing

```
// somewhere:
var resultPromise = startProcess(…);
```

```
// elsewhere:
await resultPromise;
… // the process is completed here
```

You don't even need to fulfill the promise with a useful result if all you need is to synchronise your tasks, but you really should. (If there's no data they are waiting for, what are they waiting for at all?)